# Replacing lines of output with custom message

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am trying to build a function that asks the user to enter a taboo word and then a filename. The script should then open the file and print it line by line, but replacing any line that has the taboo word in it with a censorship message such as ***LINE REDACTED***.  I'm just stuck on the last part which is adding a censorship message.  This is what I have so far:

```
print('Please enter a taboo word and a filename, separated by a comma: ')
filename = input('>')
while True:
    try:
        file = open(filename)
        line = file.readline()
        while line != "":
            print(line)
        file.close()
        break
```

Comment: Indent your code if you can

Answer (score 0):

This could work.

```
print('Please enter a taboo word and a filename, separated by a comma: ')
word, filename = input('>').split(",")
file = open(filename)
line = file.readline()
while line:
    print(line.replace(word, "LINE REDACTED"))
    line = file.readline()
file.close()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `while` loop nor the `try` block:

```
print('Please enter a taboo word and a filename, separated by a comma: ')
filename = input('>')
info = filename.split(',')

with open(info[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if info[0] in line:
            print('LINE REDACTED')
        else:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Please enter a taboo word and a filename, separated by a comma: ')
taboo, filename = input('>').split(',')
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line if taboo not in line else 'LINE REDACTED\n', end='')
```