# Python: How to go through a file and replace curse words with a "censored"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I want a script that opens a file, and then goes through the file and sees if the file contains any curse words. If a line in the file contains a curse word, then I want to replace that line with "CENSORED". So far, I think I'm just messing up the code somehow because I'm new to Python:

```
filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
censor = input("Enter the curse word that you want censored: ")

with open(filename)as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if censor in line:
            fi.write(fi.replace(line, "CENSORED"))
    print(fi)
```

I am new to this, so I'm probably just messing something up...

Line, as in This code (if "Hat" was a curse word):

```
There Is 
A 
Hat
```

Would be:

```
There Is 
A 
CENSORED
```

Comment: You're opening the file in read mode you can't write.

Comment: Duplicate of another homework problem. Probably your classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885457/replacing-lines-of-output-with-custom-message

Comment: Oh interesting! I'll have to check into writing the info to a new file. Thanks, also, at least we're trying! I just want to finally get a good night's sleep tonight..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write to the same file your are reading, for two reasons:

- You opened the file in read-only mode, you cannot write to such a file. You'd have to open the file in read-write mode (using `open(filename, mode='r+')`) to be able to do what you want.
- You are replacing data as you read, with lines that are most likely going to be shorter or longer. You cannot do that in a file. For example, replacing the word `cute` with `censored` would create a longer line, and that would overwrite not just the old line but the start of the *next* line as well.

You need to write out your changed lines to a *new* file, and at the end of that process replace the old file with the new.

Note that your `replace()` call is also incorrect; you'd call it on the line:

```
line = line.replace(censor, 'CENSORED')
```

The easiest way for you to achieve what you want is to use the [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html); it'll let you replace a file in-place, as it'll handle writing to another file and the file swap for you:

```
import fileinput

filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
censor = input("Enter the curse word that you want censored: ")

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    line = line.replace(censor, 'CENSORED')
    print(line, end='')
```

The `print()` call is a little magic here; the `fileinput` module temporarily replaces `sys.stdout` meaning that `print()` will write to the replacement file rather than your console. The `end=''` tells `print()` not to include a newline; that newline is already part of the original `line` read from the input file.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
censor = input("Enter the curse word that you want censored: ")

# Open the file, iterate through the lines and censor them, storing them in lines list
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [line.replace(censor, 'CENSORED').strip() for line in f]

# If you want to re-write the censored file, re-open it, and write the lines
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

We're using a list comprehension to censor the lines of the file.

If you want to replace the *entire line*, and not just the word, replace

```
lines = [line.replace(censor, 'CENSORED').strip() for line in f]
```

with

```
lines = ['CENSORED' if censor in line else line.strip() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
censor = input("Enter the curse word that you want censored: ")

with open(filename)as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if censor in line:
            print("CENSORED")
        else:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as data:
    the_lines = data.readlines()

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as data:
    for line_content in the_lines:

        if curse_word in line_content:
            data.write('Censored')

        else:
            data.write(line_content)
```

Comment: this will replace the entire line containing a curse word with "Censored".

Comment: That's exactly what he wanted in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have only opened the file for reading.  Some options:

- Read the whole file in, do the replacement, and write it over the original file again.
- Read the file line-by-line, process and write the lines to a new file, then delete the old file and rename in the new file.
- Use the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module, which does all the work for you.

Here's an example of the last option:

```
import fileinput,sys
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1):
    line = line.replace('bad','CENSORED')
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

And use:

```
test.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Each file will be edited in place.